# How do include different HTML pages with Javascript/Jquery/HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know iframes accomplishes this, but I want to find out how to do it without iframe if possible. I have for example 4 pages.

index.html
1.html
2.html
3.html

Where index.html has 3 links. if I click on link 1 on the index.html page, all the html content in 1.html is loaded in. If I clikc on link 2, then 2.html is loaded in.

How do I accomplish this with Jquery/Javascript/HTML only? (No serverside)

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you can use the `get()` or `load()` functions to get the contents of a page. If you use `get` you can then `append` it to an element in your current page, or use the `html` function to overwrite existing content in that element.

Using `load` is simpler:

`$("#yourElementId").load("1.html");`

Answer (score 1):

As other folks suggested, `.load()` may be your friend here. Additionally, note that you can load specific parts of the requested page. This example is from [the API doc for load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

It takes the element with ID `container` from the results of `ajax/test.html` and loads it into the 
local element with ID `result`. This technique may be more of what you want, particularly if you're trying to combine multiple pages into one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method pretty easily and it gives you a bit more flexibility than the load method (e.g. you can specify you don't want to get a cached version of the page).

```
<div id="results"></div>

$.ajax({
  url: "1.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
```